# Graph API too slow - other way to get user info

Tags: facebook-graph-api, time, get, facebook-fql

I am getting the user info through Facebook Graph API using the following codes:

```
try{
        $home = $facebook->api("/$user/home");
        $feed = $facebook->api("/$user/feed");
 ...
```

What I get:

```
 Array
(
[data] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1110904xxx
                [from] => Array
                    (
                        [category] => Computers/internet website
                        [name] => Test
                        [id] => 111090485635468
                    )

                [message] => Testing app for Facebook
                [picture] => https://fbcdn-photos-a.akamaihd.net/xxx
                [link] => http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?xxx
                [icon] => https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/rsrc.php/xx

 ...
```

And to display correctly:

```
<?php $msg = $home['data']['0']['message'];
echo $msg; ?>
```

I will do some questions to avoid creating a lot of topics:

1. Am I doing right?
2. It takes A LOT of time to load the info. Is there other way to get user home feed? Can you please show me an example how to geed the user home feed?
3. There is other tags like *status* and timeline_photo. How can I make to identify, in code, what the user posted? If was a status update, or a photo update.

Thanks a lot! God bless you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I doing right?

Yes, your solution is fine.

> It takes A LOT of time to load the info. Is there other way to get
>   user home feed? Can you please show me an example how to geed the user
>   home feed?

You're not gonna find anything quicker than that. Odds are that the bottleneck is in your server. Search for speed issues there.

> There is other tags like status and timeline_photo. How can I make to
>   identify, in code, what the user posted? If was a status update, or a
>   photo update.

There is a `type` field returned for each post. Inspect that to figure out what type it is. For example: $home['data']['0']['type']

Comment: Ok, but, how about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641925/graph-api-vs-fql-which-is-faster

Says:

    "Results :

    graph api: 1.28320002556

    graph api with FQL: 0.744100093842

    FQL via rest api: 0.544199943542

The basic FQL is much faster, the FQL via graph api is ok, but graph api is waaay too slow... And you will get a bunch of useless stuff with the graph api"

Thanks.

Comment: Best practices include defining which fields you want to be returned with the `fields` parameter

Comment: P.S - Read the accepted answer of the link you posted. It's exactly what I'm saying.